# Run update on multiple tables in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have lake dataset which take data from a OLTP system, with the nature of transactions we have lot of updates the next day, so to keep track of the latest record we are using active_flag = '1'.
We also created a update script which retires old records and updates active_flag = '0'.

Now the main question: how can i execute a update statement by changing table name automatically(programmatically).
I know we have a option of using cloudfunctions but it'll expire in 9 mins and I have atleast 350 tables to update.
Has anyone faced this situation earlier??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do this with [Cloud Workflows](https://cloud.google.com/workflows).

There you setup the template calls to Bigquery as a substeps, and then you pass a list of tables, and loop through the items and invoke the BigQuery step for each item/table.

I wrote an article with samples that you can adapt: [Automate the execution of BigQuery queries with Cloud Workflows](https://medium.com/google-cloud/automate-the-execution-of-bigquery-queries-with-cloud-workflows-9fffe0557dbb)

Comment: Thank you! will look into this looks interesting.